# How do you force reloading of Today extension binary

Tags: ios, ios8, today-extension

As I install my app that contains widget updates from TestFlight onto my device, the new binary for my Today extension does not seem to take over. Only after restarting my device I start seeing the desired changes

Is there any way to force reloading of the binary?
So far I increment CFBundleVersion in both plist files for the extension and main app. However, this doesn't have any effect

Any insight would be greatly appreciated

Comment: If you click the edit button in the Today view and remove and add the extension back, does that fix it?